# Removing n elements across an integer vector in r

Tags: r

I have an integer vector X where each element in the vector represents the number of individuals in distinct populations. I want to randomly remove y individuals across these populations.
This would be analogous to having 3 populations of 10 individuals each (c(10, 10, 10)) where I want to randomly remove 5 individuals across the three populations such that one possible random outcome is c(8, 10, 7). This is different from subset whole elements (populations) from the x vector, which would be easy with the sample base function.

```
x=c(10, 10, 10)
y=5
>x2=mystery_function(x, y)
>x2
9,8,8 #so sum(x)=sum(x2)+y
```

Any thoughts of how to efficiently do this? I feel like I am missing an obvious solution...

Comment: `x` does not contain `0`.

Comment: can you provide a few more examples demonstrating edge cases and constraints on the problem?  this kind of solver could be very expensive when `x` has many elements.

Comment: So simply speaking, you want y elements from he vector x and their sum is y? This sounds like a variation of the [subset sum problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)?

Comment: My brain's not working very well.. but my initial thought is this. you generate vector that identifies your individuals ```id = rep(1:3,each=10)```

Comment: you randomly sample 25 individuals from this and tabulate ```table(sample(id,25))```

Comment: @StupidWolf I've bundled your suggestion into a function and put it up as an answer

Comment: I re-optimized the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **@StupidWolf** 's suggestion I've written the following function :

```r
samp <- function(x,y) table(sample(rep(1:length(x), x), sum(x)-y))
```

```r
> population <- c(10, 10, 10) 
> (samp(population, 5)-> population)

1 2 3 
9 8 8 
> (samp(population, 5)-> population)

1 2 3 
8 7 5 
> (samp(population, 5)-> population)

1 2 3 
8 4 3 
> (samp(population, 5)-> population)

1 2 3 
6 2 2 
> (samp(population, 5)-> population)

1 2 3 
2 1 2 
> (samp(population, 5)-> population)
< table of extent 0 >
```